# Trigger array element calculation on access

Tags: perl

Is there any Perl API that would allow me to execute code on the reading of an array element? I'm thinking something like (or maybe it can?) [Variable::Magic](https://metacpan.org/module/Variable%3a%3aMagic) and how would I do it? The end objective would be to essentially recalculate the element value on any access (lazy evaluation), but I don't want to constrain functions like `grep`,`map`,`natatime` to be unusable.

Comment: You need to override the basic function, so you need `tie` (or a custom magic handler if you're willing to drop to C/XS land). See [Tie::Array](http://search.cpan.org/perdoc?Tie::Array) for skeletons you can build on. I don't see how this will help achieve lazy evaluation, though.

Comment: @ikegami I'm not sure I understand "how this will help achieve lazy evaluation". My understanding of lazy evaluation is do not calculate until the value is needed. If I only executed the calculations on read of an element, would that not be lazy?

Comment: Won't help you for `for`, `grep`, `map`, or any other operator. They don't read from arrays, but from the list returned by `@array`.

Comment: You'd have to tie the variable, which is about 10 times slower than normal access. I'd suggest instead modelling it as an object, perhaps with `@{}` overloaded so it can be used as an array reference.

Comment: What sort of data is this?  Is there a lot of data?  Or is it expensive to calculate?  Or are there big gaps between the indexes?

Comment: potentially a lot of data, realistically this is me being annoyed at the most common way of converting my large sets of stuff that comes out of the database and into objects, that's not really expensive for small sets, but could be for large ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several modules on CPAN for lazy arrays.  [Data::Lazy](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aLazy), [Variable::Lazy](https://metacpan.org/module/Variable%3a%3aLazy), [Tie::Array::Lazy](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aArray%3a%3aLazy) and [Variable::Magic](https://metacpan.org/module/Variable%3a%3aMagic).

Data::Lazy and Tie::Array::Lazy both tie.  Tying is very slow, about 10 times slower than a normal array, and about 3 times slower than an object.  Tying may kill the performance benefits of laziness.

Variable::Lazy is different.  Its actually replacing the variable with a chunk of code at compile time using Devel::Declare magic.  Unfortunately it appears to only work on scalars. :-/

Variable::Magic is... magic.  Its more for annotating variables than controlling them.

I would suggest instead inverting the problem.  Write the thing as an object which can be as lazy as it likes.  This is faster, more flexible and potentially more featureful and less buggy than a tie.  For grep, map and the like, provide an [overload](http://perldoc.perl.org/overload.html#Overloadable-Operations) it so it can be used as an array ref.  The overload won't be lazy, but grep and map must work on the whole list anyway and tie isn't going to do you any better.  And object may be able to provide more efficient search and transform methods.

Comment: My initial thought was to base the object on or around the modified array... but being you, I can't really argue. Though I will be fair and say I read the Variable::Magic docs and all of it's access methods seemed to be for scalars or hashes, I couldn't figure out what I might use for array access.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy lists is one of [`List::Gen`](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aGen)'s fortés.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this article from brian d foy useful: http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/blog/300 . In particular this code does lazy evaluation on and (infinite) tied array.

```
use 5.012;

{
package Tie::Array::InfiniteSquares;

    use parent qw(Tie::Array);
    use Carp qw(carp);
    use Config qw(%Config);

    # mandatory methods
    sub TIEARRAY {
        bless {}, $_[0];
        }
    sub FETCH {
        my( $self, $index ) = @_;
        $index ** 2;
        }

    sub FETCHSIZE { 0x7F_FF_FF_FF } # still problems here

    sub STORE     { carp "You can't touch this!" }
    sub STORESIZE { carp "You can't touch this!" }
    sub EXISTS    { 1 }
    sub DELETE    { carp "You can't touch this!" }

}

tie my @array, 'Tie::Array::InfiniteSquares';

while( my( $index, $value ) = each @array )
    {
    say "Item is $value at index $index";
    }
```

Now assuming you actual dataset isn't infinite, then when you construct your tied class correctly you can `each` to do lazy evaluation. `map`, `grep`, `for` etc will evalulate the whole list before acting, but they will still work.